# pulseaudio-equalizer won't start

Tags: equalizer

Hey I have a huge problem, **pulseaudio-equalizer_2.7.0.2-2** won't start after clicking it, actually it doesn't do anything at all. It worked well on ubuntu 12.10 but now, after reinstalling fresh copy of ubuntu 13.04 it installs fluently but does not do anything else, no errors no pop-ups, nothing, what should I do to make it work? Maybe I need to install some kind of packages?

As I mentioned before I'm using **ubuntu 13.04 (32 bit)**

Answer (score 4):

Just create new folder ".pulse"  in your home

Answer (score -2):

i have the same problem in Ubuntu Raring 13.04 and i can solve with this solution, because the autor not yet design a version of this program for ubuntu Saucy Salamander, (13.10) that i am using now.

The equalizer for pulseaudio not installed well in ubuntu 13.04 because it was designed to run until such time ubuntu 12.04 .

```
The solution I found is:

go to the terminal , in the dash , open it and press enter:

With the open terminal write :

Code :

sudo add -apt -repository ppa : psyke83/ppa

( This command searches the repository , called PPA where this pulseaudio equalizer , but it will not find the file )

Write apt- get update and press enter to update . Dara a message that the repository pulseaudio -equalizer for Raring not yet .

Code :

sudo apt- get update

Then reboot .

The solution is to search the site ppa : psyke83/ppa in google and get pulseaudio -equalizer first :

http://ppa.launchpad.net/psyke83/ppa...er_2.7_all.deb

Once downloaded this file, you need to install two units :

ladspa -sdk
swh -plugins

From where to get :

Ubuntu Packages looking Raring :

http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubu...untu1_i386.deb

http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu//po...5+1-7_i386.deb

When trying to install with Gdebi , you may ask the other files and do not install them. In that case you need to open pulseaudio - equalize and allow the system to download and install the files by pressing install the machine connected to the network. When installing the program everything seems normal
but the run does not work. These are the causes and how the fix :

File pulseaudio -equalizer installed and pulseaudio pulseaudio -equalizer -equalizer -gtk in usr / bin , with presets files in share / pulseaudio -equalizer , containing the configuration of the sound system. The system when trying to run , look at the user account to search the hidden folder . / Pulse , to find the same configuration does not exist.
To create it you should go to Nautilus , preferences, and choose to show hidden files , close and reopen it to see the hidden files . Then you can create a new folder called . / Press. and left open nautilus

The system also seeks the. / Presets , which should be in / home / user account / . / Press / presets , which will be empty. To copy the files you requested , open pulseaudio - equalizer_2.7_all.deb with archive manager :

Then go open each folder to this location / usr / share / pulseaudio -equalizer . Here you will find the presets folder , which is precisely where the program asks . It can be extracted to the folder / home / user account, and from there copy it to the folder. / Pulse , and stay well :

/ home / user account. / press / presets

The system installs a file called pulseaudio - equalizer.py in the / usr / share / pulseaudio -equalizer , and this tells how to run the equalizer.
The script looks for a file called gnome -volume- control.svg in this folder, but the file is not found.
Inside the terminal , it should execute the command : sudo nautilus, then type your password and search for this file in the folder usr / share / pulseaudio -equalizer and abirlo with gedit for editing.
Once you open the file with gedit by double clicking within the pulseaudio - equalizer.py file to look for this line:

icon = self.window.set_icon_from_file ("/ usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/gnome-volume-control.svg " )

Changing to this location :

icon = self.window.set_icon_from_file ("/ usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/16/gnome-volume-control.svg " )

Close the file and all open windows and open the program from the unity dash looking pulseaudio -equalizer . These steps solve the problem as the author of the program designed a version for Ubuntu 13.
```

Comment: All of your links are crippled and thus rendered useless. Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/376310/edit) and fix the links. While you are at it, please also give your formatting a bit more love.